# Manually select approver

Tags: approval-process

I have created an Approval Process. In the approval step creation, at step 3, the approver has to be selected but I am not getting the option to let the user manually select the approver. The only option that I am getting is Automatically Assign to Approvers option. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I tried to recreate this and really couldn't. Below is the screen that is displayed for Step 3 on the Approval Step creation.

[image: Step 3 Approval Process Step]

This is in a Winter '13 Org. The following screenshot is my test setup I used to generate that screenshot:

[image: Approval Process]

I researched a bit and couldn't find any information related to removing that option. Can you take a quick look at my approval process setup and tell me if it is similar to yours? Anything glaringly different? If not, I would suggest opening a case with Salesforce support. To do this, click on "Help" after loging into your org. Click "Contact Support". Click "Open a Case". Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I am getting the manual selection option when I created a new approval process using Jumpstart wizard. But I still do not get this option when using standard wizard to create the approval process.

Comment: The Jumpstart Wizard? Are you talking about creating an Approval Process step or an Approval Process? You specify the approver on the step level, not the Approval Process level.

Comment: The Jumpstart wizard gave this option when the approval process is created.

Comment: It does that because the Jumpstart wizard automatically creates a first step for you. The Standard Approval Process wizard does not do that. You need to create the first step afterwards. The approver is specified on each step, not on the entire approval process. You are looking at two different things.

Comment: Yes I know but when I use the Standard wizard and create the approval step (after approval process is created) I do not get that option.

Comment: That is really weird. Is there anything specific about your approval process that is preventing this? In the screenshots I posted, is my approval process different from yours in any specific way? Would you be able to take some screenshots of what you are doing and edit your original question to include them? I have no idea why this isn't working and I am really intrigued now.

Comment: Please see the answer below from Leah McGowen-Hare as I have confirmed that is indeed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check and make sure you do not have "Allow approvers to access the approval page from within the salesforce.com application, or externally from a wireless-enabled mobile device" selected this will take away the ability to manually select an apporver

Comment: I've confirmed that this is the answer.